# HTML JQUERY Select convert to Spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I have Select element , that populates dynamically 
Simplified example, using sample static values- it would look something like this:

```
<form method="get" action=colours.php">
  <select name="id">
   <option value="1">Red</option>
   <option value="2">Green</option>
   <option value="3">Yellow</option>
  </select>
<button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

My goal is to create a Spinner , that changes box value and URL value by going Up or Down.
If its possible , button would not appear.

Comment: Sounds like a great project. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery-UI Spinner for what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/spinner/